# __doPostBack of asp:button in Gridview using onChange event of fileUpload

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have an asp:button in an itemTemplate in a gridview with a fileUpload control tied to it. Following the code from here -> [Single Click File Upload in ASP.Net](http://www.bitsmonkey.com/2014/04/simply-notes-2-single-click-file-upload.html)

However, I'm stuck at

```
 function clickSeverControl() {

        __doPostBack('<%= lnkUpload.ClientID %>', 'OnClick');
    }
```

**because my button is embedded in a gridview and I have no idea how to get it's xxx.ClientID  as event.target of __doPostBack.**

Below is my code.

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function uploadImage()
{
    document.getElementById("FileUploadControl").click();
}
function confirmUpload()
{
    __doPostBack(<WHAT TO PUT HERE>, 'OnClick');
}
</script>
```

aspx:

```
 <asp:gridview id="gvDirector" runat="server"<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Signature" itemstyle-width="150" itemstyle-horizontalalign="Center">
     <itemtemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnViewSignature" runat="server" Text="View" CommandName="view"
        CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" />
        <asp:FileUpload id="FileUploadControl" runat="server" style="display: none;" onChange="confirmUpload()" />   
        <asp:Button ID="btnUploadSignature" runat="server"  text="Upload" CommandName="upload" OnClientClick="uploadImage(); return false;" OnClick="btnUpload_Click"
        CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>"/>                                           
     </itemtemplate> 
 </asp:gridview>
```

**I have tried using `$("#FileUploadControl")` but the server side onClick() event doesn't trigger.** Would appreciate any input or directions. Thank You.

Below is a screenshot of what I'm trying to accomplish.

[image]

The 'Upload' button should trigger fileUpload control once user has selected a file, the upload begins automatically without an additional button to 'submit' the file.

*P.S I've barely a year of experience meddling with .net and C#, if possible, please **ELI5**.*

Comment: What's your main goal are you trying to open browse window and select image or you want to open it, select the file and later save the image in Database?

Comment: The latter. Open the browse window, select a .jpeg file, open it and immediately save in Database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How do I extract the name from HTML collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33281268/how-do-i-extract-the-name-from-html-collection)

This would yield the answer to my above question on clientID but __doPostBack would not be a good solution to my original problem.

It was actually pretty straightforward. What I wanted to do has already been answered here in case anyone is curious.

[FileUpload between onClientClick and onClick](http://forums.asp.net/t/1806676.aspx?onclick%20and%20onclientclick%20input%20control)