# How do I extract the name from HTML collection?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, aspxgridview

Here's the step through of the javascript.

[image]

I have an HTMLCollection, I want to loop through it and extract the object with the ID of FileUploadControl. How do I do it?

Here's my code, how do I proceed?

```
    function uploadImage(lnk)
{
    var row = lnk.parentNode.parentNode;
    var rowIndex = row.rowIndex - 1;
    var abc = row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName("input");
    var arr = [].slice.call(abc);
}
```

Comment: `abc.namedItem('FileUploadControl') `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do it:

```
abc.namedItem('FileUploadControl')
```

But beware that:

> Different browsers behave differently when there are more than one
>   elements matching the string used as an index (or namedItem's
>   argument). Firefox 8 behaves as specified in DOM 2 and DOM4, returning
>   the first matching element. WebKit browsers and Internet Explorer in
>   this case return another HTMLCollection and Opera returns a NodeList
>   of all matching elements.

From [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection).

This means that if in your markup you had something like this:

```
<div id='id'>Foo</div>
<div id='id'>Bar</div>
```

browsers would behave differently when executing the following code:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('div').namedItem('id')`
```

Firefox would return an [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement), while IE would return another HTMLCollection.

To solve this inconsistencies, you could apply a function to return the same object.

```
retElement( abc.namedItem('id') );
```

Which could be something like this:

```
var retElement = function(oElem) {
  //Firefox
  if (oElem instanceof window.HTMLElement)
    return oElem;
  //IE and WebKit
  if (oElem instanceof window.HTMLCollection)
    return oElem.item(0);
};
```

Comment: Thanks @Federico. I'm lost at your "beware" because I'm pretty new to javascript. Are you able to ELI5? Thank you for the help still. Cheers.

Comment: @f0rfun No problemo. I updated my answer to clarify this issue. Let me know if there is something you don't understand.

Comment: thanks bud. You've been a great help. Have a great weekend.